# Is it possible to compose paths and evaluate the result in AWS Step Functions?

Tags: aws-step-functions

Is it possible to compose paths in AWS Step Functions? I'm attempting to do something like this:

State Input:

```json
{
  "query": "genre",
  "movies": [
    {
      "genre": "crime",
      "title": "Reservoir Dogs",
      "year": 1992
    }
  ]
}
```

Composing Paths in Parameters:

```json
{
  "value1.$": "$.query",
  "value2.$": "$.movies[0].{$.query}"
}
-- or --
{
  "value1.$": "$.query",
  "value2.$": "$.movies[0].{$.value1}"
}
```

Expected Result:

```json
{
  "value1": "genre",
  "value2": "crime"
}
```

Actual Result:

```
No results for path: '$.movies[0].{$.query}' specified for the field 'value2.$'  in input JSON.

----

No results for path: '$.movies[0].{$.value1}' specified for the field 'value2.$'  in input JSON.
```